# how the getCookies() function will call the cookies that are stored in another java class

Tags: java, servlets, cookies

```
package com.session;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/srv1")
public class TestSrv1 extends HttpServlet{
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        Cookie cookie1,cookie2,cookie3,cookie4;
        cookie1=new Cookie("ts", "hyd");
        cookie2=new Cookie("kdp", "kadapa");
        cookie3=new Cookie("ka", "blr");
        res.addCookie(cookie1);
        res.addCookie(cookie2);
        //cookie is valid for 1hr reagardless of wheather user quites the browser,reboots computer or whatever
        cookie4=new Cookie("vjw", "vijayawada");
        cookie3.setMaxAge(3600);
        cookie4.setMaxAge(3600);
        res.addCookie(cookie3);
        res.addCookie(cookie4);

        PrintWriter pw=res.getWriter();
        pw.println("added cookies successfully");

    }

}
```

here i am creating the cookies in one java class and calling the same cookies from other class using req.getCookies() function how will the request object gets all the cookie objects that are created in the previous class with out the reference of that class.

Comment: Retrieve the cookies via request object stored from browser cache

Comment: Cookies are stored in browser cache when sent via server response

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are present at client side so when ever we create the cookies obj and add the values into cookies object those values are stored into the cookies object at client side so whether you call those cookies object in first servlet or second servlet or any other servlet the data is getting retrieved from the client only using req.getCookies() method.